# How to extract more than one value and print a correct output in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to extract more than one value out of a filename and give it out to a *.csv file (separate with a semicolon ;) in a specific order on 1 line.

Unfortunately it just puts the date out in the file and the other values directly in the shell, like you command this with an echo

```
activemq
aomaap-report
aomaap-stats
5.14.1
5.14.1.rar
1.1.2
1.1.2.war
2.1.1
2.1.1.war
intil10377.echbruedom.local
```

the date is shown im my *.csv file:

```
Tue Jul 30 10:44:44 CEST 2019
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
```

Here is my actual command.
`ls -1 $path | grep -E ^.*ar$ | grep -Eo '[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,}...\w\w\w\w'; ls -1 $path | sed -n 's/.*-\(.*\)\..*/\1/p'; hostname; date > test4.csv`

I want all values in one line and order in my file. Like this:

```
activemq;5.14.1;intil10377;Jul 30 10:44:44
~
~
~
~
~
```

Can someone help me out? Thnx in advance..

Comment: I can see you made some effort for showing info. It would help when you showed us 5 files `ls` returns, and the resulting 5 lines in the output. How do you want the date? Default like `Tue Jul 30 10:44:44 CEST 2019` or converted into `Jul 30 10:44:44` ?

Comment: Hi Walter A
Thank you for asking me. The result how the output is, is showing up here. The date should be converted like:
Tue Jul 30 10:44:44  --> would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ ls -1 $path | grep -E ^.*ar$ | grep -Eo '[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,}...\w\w\w\w'; ls -1 $path | sed -n 's/.*-\(.*\)\..*/\1/p'; hostname; date; } | tr '\n' ';' | sed 's/;$/\n/' > test4.csv
```

- Enclose your whole your command inside `{` `}` braces to capture output of all commands
- Replace all newlines with `;` using `tr '\n' ';'`
- Then replace the last `;` with a newline using `sed 's/;$/\n/'`
- Redirect the output to the `test4.csv` file
- Remember to quote your variables. The `ls -1 $path` looks unsafe, better `ls -1 "$path"`
- Using `find` could be preferred over using `ls`. You could save cpu with some `find "$path" \! -name '*ar' -a -regex "something"` etc.

Comment: Hi Kamil

Sorry, have to ask again. Tried now your code, but doesn't get it..


here is a fragment of what happend:
```
[jboss@intil10377 aca_aomstats]$ ./select_name_version.sh
./select_name_version.sh: line 31: {ls: command not found
5.14.1
5.14.1.rar
1.1.2
1.1.2.war
2.1.1
2.1.1.war
intil10377.echbruedom.local
./select_name_version.sh: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./select_name_version.sh: line 34: `date; } tr '\n' ';' | sed 's/;$/\n/' > test4.csv'
[jboss@intil10377 aca_aomstats]$ cd deployments/```

Comment: Here is what I wanna extract from: 
```jboss@intil10377 deployments]$ ll
total 74304
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 jboss jboss  9273317 Jul 24  2018 activemq-rar-5.14.1.rar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jboss jboss       23 Jul 24  2018 activemq-rar-5.14.1.rar.deployed
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 jboss jboss 24591797 Mar 22 11:27 aomaap-reports-1.1.2.war
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jboss jboss       24 Mar 22 11:27 aomaap-reports-1.1.2.war.deployed
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 jboss jboss 42201818 Jul 16 13:07 aomaap-stats-2.1.1.war
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jboss jboss        1 Jul 12 08:14  test.txt```

Comment: `; } tr` - there is a `|` after `}`.

Comment: Hi Kamil.. was successful. How can I rate your help?